# Alphabetic citation style and authortitle style combined with Biblatex

Tags: citing, biblatex

I im using Biblatex as my package with biber as the backend and following package declarations:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=trad-abbrv,
citestyle=alphabetic,
minalphanames=3,
maxalphanames=3,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

I want the keys of the citations to appear in the alphabetic style e.g.

> [Azu97], [LB17], ...

but I also want the names of the authors to appear as family1, given1; family2, given2; ... in the literature.

To top it of, I would like all of the letters of the name to be written in capital in the ACM-manner.

How can I achieve this with biblatex?

[image]

This is an example of how I want my citations to look like.

My current declarations end up in a weird mix, where the citestyle in the document is as needed, but in the literature the citations keys are numeric.

Minimal example:

**document.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
twoside, 
12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=trad-abbrv,
%giveninits=true,
citestyle=alphabetic,
%citestyle=trad-abbrv,
minalphanames=3,
maxalphanames=3,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\begin{document}

    This is the text that cites something \cite{Shamsee.2015}. 
    
    This is also an important source \cite{Park.20190912}.

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

**literature.bib**

```
@book{Shamsee.2015,
 author = {Shamsee, N. and Klebanov, D. and Fayed, H. and Afrose, A. and Karakok, O.},
 year = {2015},
 title = {CCNA Data Center DCICT 640-916 Official Cert Guide},
 url = {https://books.google.de/books?id=-0GkBgAAQBAJ},
 publisher = {{Pearson Education}},
 isbn = {9780133860450}
}

@article{Park.20190912,
 author = {Park, Jina},
 year = {2019-09-12},
 title = {MAXST Launches MAXST AR SDK Version 5.0 Incorporating New Tracker That Fused MAXST and Google/Apple's AR Technology},
 url = {https://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2019-12-09/maxst-launches-maxst-ar-sdk-version-5-0-incorporating-new-tracker-that-fused-maxst-and-google-apple-s-ar-technology},
 urldate = {2021-04-09},
 journal = {Bloomberg},
 file = {d37e4ccc-52ba-4082-8736-f8224fbe6b42:C\:\\Users\\Manuel\\AppData\\Local\\Swiss Academic Software\\Citavi 6\\ProjectCache\\xzsmbvyd3w5p1cckmz29ax2sexab47m14nye6g3lk0ztbz\\Citavi Attachments\\d37e4ccc-52ba-4082-8736-f8224fbe6b42.pdf:pdf}
}
}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I have added a minimal reprodcucible example to my post. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
%style=trad-abbrv,
giveninits,
style=alphabetic,
minalphanames=3,
maxalphanames=3,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome!